# What is the name of the symmetry of a bracelet transposition?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, symmetry

Take a [bracelet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29) with colored beads on it. Normally two bracelets belong to the same equivalence class under rotations and reflections. For an example, consider the bracelet denoted by the word `abcdec`:

```
cabcde ecabcd decabc cdecab ... (rotations)
cedcba dcbace ... (reflections)
```

Consider the larger class where two bracelets are equivalent *if all local bead pairings are preserved*. From our example we have the multiset `{ab, bc, cd, de, ec, ca}`. The right-left ordering, `ba` vs `ab` doesn't matter. Clearly rotations and reflections preserve bead pairings, but so does:

```
abcedc
```

where we've transposed the `e` and the `d`. How do you describe this symmetry?

Comment: If it helps, your bead pairings are the edges of a multi-graph, and a word in the equivalence class is the same thing as a Euler circuit of the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can interpret the bead pairings as the edges in a multi-graph whose vertices are the bead labels. Each words in the corresponding equivalence class corresponds to the sequence of vertices in a Euler circuit of the graph, and vice versa.

We get a one-to-one correspondence if we consider multiple edges between a pair of vertices to be indistinguishable, so that a Euler circuit is completely determined by its vertices.

Comment: This is perfect, and yet I have a (perhaps unfair) followup: how did you notice this observation in the first place? Is this a well-known fact (which does seem to make sense in hindsight) or did you follow so methodological process to determine the relation between a graph and the symmetry of the problem?

Comment: Nothing deep; a graph is just one way to gather a collection of pairs together. Adjacency graphs are a typical application of graphs, and you had even mentioned graphs in a previous version your question. So with that on my mind, I speculatively considered how the problem would look phrased in those terms, and it happened to turn out rather nicely.